# AWS EC2 - browser can't connect to server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to point my static portfolio url, laurenleague.io to AWS EC2 so I can build a site there.

I've followed a tutorial on setting AWS EC2 up and installing Apache on it. It seems like I've done everything right, including enabling HTTP on port 80 in the inbound rules of the security groups. I can ssh into the machine, so my key pair is fine. I can also ping the public dns, public ip, and my new url and get a response.

However, my browser can't connect to the server.

In my security groups on AWS, it says port 80 is open and accepting traffic from anywhere. But when I run nmap from my shell, it says port 80 is closed! Why??

Please help, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: on other hand if you have static website you can use s3 and cloudfront for hosting it - no need to manage ec2 - just a suggestion http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html

Comment: I gotta ask - did Apache stay running?  I've had configuration errors where Apache doesn't start.

Comment: can you visit your web using IP (Public IP)?

Comment: @stdunbar I'm not sure if Apache is still running, and not sure how to check. I suspected that it stopped so I searched stack overflow for answers on how to check the status of it, though nothing was really clear. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @webDev no, the public IP doesn't work in the browser either :/

Comment: What about using the URL(Domain name)  provided by the amazon NOT using your domain name.

Comment: If you can ssh, then just do a either a "ps -efww | grep httpd" or a "ps -efww | grep apache".  It depends on how you installed Apache and your O/S version.  You should be able to see logs in /var/log/apache2 (you'll need to be root to do this - i.e. "sudo su -" )

Comment: @webDev yes, I tried the amazon url in the browser. Still can't connect to server.

Comment: @stdunbar "ps -efww | grep httpd" returned this "ec2-user  3636  3606  0 23:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd" I'm not really sure what that means, and I tried doing a "sudo /var/log/apache2" but the shell says it's an invalid command. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, just not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!

Thanks to @stdunbar, I logged into my machine and found out that Apache server on my EC2 had stopped! I found this out by ssh-ing into it and running:

```
sudo ps -efww | grep httpd
```

which returned nothing. So I rebooted Apache with:

```
sudo service httpd start
```

And now it works!